# How make a firemonkey HUD window

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, firemonkey, hud

I wanna to replicate the HUD functionality of https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD in Delphi with firemonkey.

This is what look like in iPhone:

[image: HUD]

The main issue is how make the form semi-transparent & completely remove the borders.

Comment: Please edit your question, and post a screen capture or image of what you're trying to do here instead of just using an external link. If the external link disappears or isn't available for some reason, it makes your question meaningless to others in the future. Thanks. :)

Comment: You can't make a form semi-transparent, but you can make it completely transparent and use a semi-transparent (opacity < 1) shape on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your Firemonkey HD form, set it's `Fill.Kind` to `bkNone`, and it's `Fill.Color` to `Null`. Additionally, set it's `Transparency` property to True, and it's `BorderStyle` to `bsNone`.

Create a TRectangle (or any shape), and set the `Stroke.Kind` property to `bkNone`. Set it's `Fill.Color` to `Gray`, it's `Opacity` to 0.5.

Create a `TAniIndicator` and `TLabel` with parent of both as the form. It's `Opacity` remains at 1.0. Optionally, also create a `TImage` and make it the exact same size and position as the `TAniIndicator`.

From there, it's simply a case of working with `TFloatAnimation` on the TAniIndicator when you want to change the image (to a tick or such) and the label text to simply change to whatever message you want to display. Ideally, you simply create a procedure that accepts either a string or integer as a variable, and then modify the text and indicator/image to match that. For example;

```
Procedure TForm1.Process(Mode : Integer);
Begin
 if Mode = 1 then
 begin
  AniIndicator1.Enabled := True;
  AniIndicator1.Visible := True;
  Image1.Visible := False;
  Label1.TextAlign := TTextAlign.taCenter; // Must be called to reset alignment
  Label1.Text := 'Loading';
 End
 else if Mode = 2 then
 Begin
  AniIndicator1.Enabled := False;
  AniIndicator1.Visible := False;
  Label1.TextAlign := TTextAlign.taCenter; // Must be called to reset alignment
  Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('Tick.png');
  Image1.Visible := True;
  Label1.Text := 'Complete!';
 end;
end;
```

You can then create a tpanel in your main form, and then add the above form (that contains the `TAniIndicator, label, and rectangle`) as a child component. You then call the procedure you created with a valid mode variable and it'll run as you indicated in the code. It's easy enough to add more modes and i've done something similar with one of my own applications (although it was related to `TRectangle` rather than creating an indicator).